# How to find number of days between results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a ticket details table that stores the information of transactions.  Here is an example of the table data:

```
Ticket_Number  Detail_type_ID   Description  Date_Created   TotalAmount   Barcode 
   1                 11         Card Sale      1/1/16           5           123
   1                 1          Book           1/1/16           5            
   1                 11         Card Red       1/1/16          -5           123 
   2                 1          book           1/5/16           5
   3                 1          book           1/6/16           5
   3                 11         Card Red       1/6/16          -5           123
   4                 11         Card Sale      1/7/16           5           124
   5                 1          Book           1/7/16           5
   5                 11         Card Red       1/7/16          -5           124
   6                 11         Card Sale      1/8/16           5           123
   6                 1          Book           1/8/16           5
   6                 11         Card Red       1/8/16          -5           123
   7                 1          Book           1/9/16           5
   7                 11         Card Red       1/9/16          -5           124
```

We sell Gift cards - $5 allows you to purchase 2 books.  The gift cards are loaded with 2 books.  You'll see in the table above, in most cases, we sell a card, and a book is redeemed right away.  The customer comes back at some point, and purchases another book, with the remaining balance on the card.

What we're looking to find out is: how often are customers coming back and redeeming the balance, or how long does it take for them to deplete the card.  As you'll see - the barcode is stored in the details table, however, we do re-use the cards so we don't want that to pollute the data of the first card. Detail_Type_ID of '11' means a card sale or redemption. Based on the data above, Here is the output I'm looking for:

```
Barcode      Days_between_usage    Balance_still_remains
 123             6                       No
 124             2                       No
 123(2)          0                      Yes
```

The "balance still remains" will tell me that the card still has a balance.

How can I run a query to get to this output?

EDIT:

Based on the answer below, It looks like the first step is to break the data into sale and redeems which I've done.  I am unsure how to proceed from here.

```
Select barcode, date_created, Case When TotalAmount > 0 Then 'Sale' Else 'Redeem' end as SaleOrRedeem
From Ticketsdetails
Where  (Date_Created > '1/1/16') and (Detail_Type_ID = '11') and (barcode In (select Barcode
From Ticketsdetails as td
where Date_Created > '1/1/16') and (Detail_Type_ID = '11') and Total Amount > 0)))
Order By Barcode, date_Created
```

Which returns:

```
Barcode           Date_Created      TransType
 123                1/1/16           Sale
 123                1/1/16           Redeem
 123                1/6/16           Redeem
 124                1/7/16           Sale
 124                1/7/16           Redeem
 124                1/7/16           Sale
 123                1/8/16           Sale
 123                1/8/16           Redeem
 124                1/9/16           Redeem
```

Comment: Explain to me more about the "Balance still remains" business logic. It may be easier to have that as a 3rd column instead of another row, but I suppose that depends on what you need.

Comment: Also the ticket number. How do ticket numbers associate to the rest of the data?

Comment: I was actually just thinking about editing my question to make it a 3rd column as I'm trying to work through this.

Comment: Ticket numbers are the same for a transaction.  So, as is usually the case, the tickets details table lists each line item as a new item.  The ticket numbers are Transaction specific.  I included them incase someone, by chance, was going to use them as some sort of filter.

Comment: How do you know when card 123 is a new 123 and not an existing 123? Is it that once a card goes to 0 balance the next one is a new card? Are numbers only reused (a horrible idea, BTW) when the previous card with that number was brought to a zero balance?

Comment: Yes.  Once the card goes to 0 (used twice) the numbers are re-used.

Comment: The values in `TotalAmount` don't make sense to me. Should it be `10` when the card is sold? Or, should it be `-2.5` when one book is redeemed? Also, the rows with `Detail_type_ID=1` could be completely ignored for this problem, right? (because these transactions don't involve gift card at all, these books are paid normally, right?)

Comment: We value the "book" at $5.  SO the redemption side is $5.00.  The detail_type_id is important because we are looking for Gift Card transactions.  Essentially we sell a gift card for $5 and load $10 on the card.  Each transaction is $5. Accounting purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stab in the dark. I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements quite right.

```
with Sales as (
    select
        t.Barcode,
        t.Date_Created as Sale_Date,
        row_number() over (partition by t.Barcode order by t.Sale_Date) as Load_Seq
    from <Transactions> as t
    where Description = 'Card Sale'
    group by Barcode
),
RedemptionWindows as (
    select
        s1.Barcode,
        s1.Load_Seq
        s1.Sale_Date,
        coalesce(s2.Sale_Date, dateadd(year, 1, s1.Sale_Date)) as End_Date,
    from Sales as s1 left outer join Sales s2
        on s2.Barcode = s1.Barcode and s2.Load_Seq = s1.Load_Seq + 1
)
select
    Barcode
      + case 
             when Load_Seq > 1 
             then '(' + cast(Load_Seq as varchar(3)) + ')' 
             else '' end as Barcode,
    Days_Between_Usage,
    case when RedemptionCount < 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' Balance_Still_Remains,
    5.00 - 2.50 * RedemptionCount as Balance_Remaining
from
    RedemptionWindows as rw
    cross apply
    (
        select
            datediff(day,min(r.Date_Created),max(r.Date_Created)) as Days_Between_Usage,
            count(*) as RedemptionCount
        from <Transactions> as r /* redemptions */
        where Description = 'Card Red'
            and r.Barcode = rw.Barcode
            and r.Date_Created >= rw.Sale_Date 
            and r.Date_Created <  rw.End_Date
    ) r_summary
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  Looks like it gives me exactly what I need - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self-join or with a subquery.

Here is some pseudo-code

```
SELECT t1.Barcode, SUM(t1.Date - t2.Date)
FROM TheTable t1
JOIN TheTable t2 ON t1.Barcode=t2.Barcode
AND t1.Code = 'Redemption'
AND t2.Code = 'Sale'
GROUP BY Barcode
```

And then to get that last row you'll have to UNION with another query that generates the row you want.   You can use a CASE expression to generate a string based on whether the balance remaining is > 0 or not.   And a sub-query can be used to generate the number in parenthesis next to the Barcode.

Comment: Does this account for Cards(Essentially the barcode column) being re-used?

Comment: Account for it in what way?   I don't see anything in your question about how this should be considered.

Comment: In the last paragraph I say:  "As you'll see - the barcode is stored in the details table, however, we do re-use the cards so we don't want that to pollute the data of the first card."

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but there is no explanation of HOW the re-use affects the desired results.   What if somebody "recharges" the card while there is still a balance on it?   Then what dates do you use?

Comment: If 1 customer uses the card - and takes 15 days to use the card, then another customer gets that card, and it takes them 4 days to use the card, those results are very different...

Comment: @TabAlleman That is true, I was ambiguous. A card will be resold different times, and Shmewnix implies that he would like the results for each re-use to be in a different record.

Comment: @Shmewnix, ok, what about this:  Customer A buys the card.  Customer B later buys the same card.   How do you know which purchases go to Customer A, and which to Customer B?

Comment: It's very rare we re-load a card before it depletes.  Since this is the case, it should be assumed that date is a factor here.  SO in my above example, you'll see, the card is used, then a few days later the card is reloaded for another customer.

Comment: In that case, modify the query so that you join the Redemption to the most recent Sale (of the same barcode, obviously) that took place before it.

Answer (score 0):

The, somewhat complex, code bellow gives you the solution.

I must say - man, reusing the barcode, in the presented scenario, will force your solution to ALWAYS look backwards in the entire sales history just to devise the 'order of reusing event' on a given context.

You'd better NOT reuse barcodes or denormalize the 'reusing order' as a new column on `Ticketsdetails`.

Enjoy...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Isolate the card sale/redeem events (we are not interested in the books)
--
-- note the 'barcode_reuse_count' column
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @price_per_book MONEY

SET @price_per_book = 5

SELECT
    Ticket_Number, barcode, date_created,
    --
    CASE WHEN Description = 'Card Sale' THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
    END AS is_event_of_sale /* is this an event of card sale? */,
    --
    CASE WHEN
        Description = 'Card Sale' THEN (TotalAmount * 2) / @price_per_book /* Well, $5 HAS to mean TWO books... */
                                  ELSE TotalAmount / @price_per_book
    END AS Credit_Or_Debit_As_Books,
    --
    CONVERT(INT, NULL) AS barcode_reuse_order
INTO #card_events
FROM Ticketsdetails
WHERE Detail_Type_ID = '11'
go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- For each ticket, identify the ticket where the card in its 'barcode reuse'
-- incarnation was sold (although there should be one, and only one, barcode per
-- Ticket_Number, the query allows for more than one...)
--
-- Then, set 'barcode_reuse_order'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

WITH card_sale_event AS
(
    SELECT card_event.Ticket_Number, card_event.barcode, MAX(card_event_sale.Ticket_Number) AS Ticket_Number_Of_Sale
    FROM
        #card_events card_event
            INNER JOIN #card_events card_event_sale
            ON(
                    card_event_sale.barcode          =  card_event.barcode
                AND card_event_sale.is_event_of_sale =  1
                AND card_event_sale.Ticket_Number    <= card_event.Ticket_Number
            )
    GROUP BY card_event.Ticket_Number, card_event.barcode
)
UPDATE card_event
SET
    barcode_reuse_order =(
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT prev_card_sale_event.Ticket_Number_Of_Sale)
            /* card_event_sale may have many Ticket_Number_Of_Sale per barcode, one per Ticket_Number */
        FROM card_sale_event prev_card_sale_event
        WHERE
                prev_card_sale_event.barcode       = card_sale_event.barcode
            AND prev_card_sale_event.Ticket_Number < card_sale_event.Ticket_Number_Of_Sale
    )
FROM
    #card_events card_event
        INNER JOIN card_sale_event
        ON(
                card_sale_event.Ticket_Number = card_event.Ticket_Number
            AND card_sale_event.barcode       = card_event.barcode
        )
go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Le grand result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT
    barcode +
    CASE
        WHEN barcode_reuse_order > 0 THEN '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, barcode_reuse_order + 1) + ')'
                                     ELSE ''
    END AS barcode,
    --
    CONVERT(INT, MAX(date_created)) -
    CONVERT(INT, MIN(date_created)) AS Days_between_usage,
    --
    SUM(Credit_Or_Debit_As_Books) AS Balance
FROM #card_events
GROUP BY
    barcode +
    CASE
        WHEN barcode_reuse_order > 0 THEN '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, barcode_reuse_order + 1) + ')'
                                     ELSE ''
    END
go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Clean-up
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE #card_events
go
```

I uploaded the given data using the script below.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Ticketsdetails')
DROP TABLE Ticketsdetails
go

CREATE TABLE Ticketsdetails(
    Ticket_Number   INT,
    Detail_type_ID  INT,
    Description     VARCHAR(32),
    Date_Created    DATETIME,
    TotalAmount     MONEY,
    Barcode         VARCHAR(16)
)
go

insert into Ticketsdetails values(1, 11, 'Card Sale', '20160101', 5, '123')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(1, 1, 'Book', '20160101', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(1, 11, 'Card Red', '20160101', -5, '123 ')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(2, 1, 'book', '20160105', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(3, 1, 'book', '20160106', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(3, 11, 'Card Red', '20160106', -5, '123')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(4, 11, 'Card Sale', '20160107', 5, '124')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(5, 1, 'Book', '20160107', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(5, 11, 'Card Red', '20160107', -5, '124')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(6, 11, 'Card Sale', '20160108', 5, '123')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(6, 1, 'Book', '20160108', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(6, 11, 'Card Red', '20160108', -5, '123')
insert into Ticketsdetails values(7, 1, 'Book', '20160109', 5, NULL)
insert into Ticketsdetails values(7, 11, 'Card Red', '20160109', -5, '124')
go
```